# wrap_content height, but limited to half of parent

Tags: android, layout

What I want is to have a layout with 2 views arranged vertically. Let's call the top view A and the bottom one B. I want the amount of height given to B to be its normal height (i.e. wrap content) except that I don't want it to be given more than half of the available space. A gets what is left.

Another way to word it is that A should always get at least 50% of the available height and B should get at most 50%.

I can't seem to find an easy way to achieve that. I can set both layout heights to 0 and give them equal weights which makes them both 50% always, but if B is smaller than 50% it should be given only what it needs.

The only way I can see to do it is use a custom class for A or B and override onMeasure to constrain the height to 50% of the parent, but it seems there should be an easier way.

Comment: So what is the input for defining how large B should be? You could make a dynamic layout in your code ([Android Reference LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)).

Comment: The input for determining how large B should be is the content of B. B is a  layout (currently a fragment) that contains some fixed size content but the majority of it is a TextView whose content is dynamic. Could be a few lines of text or a long page of text. If the text in B is long and B is constrained to 50% then the text will be scrollable.

Comment: Have you looked for a way to determine how many lines of text will be in B and dynamically adjusting the height of B in accordance with that?

Comment: I think overriding a a Layout is much more straightforward than that. The height it would need to be is dependent on the height of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it now. If I understood correctly you want to have it like this:

```
if A > B -> do nothing 
if B > A & B > parent layout -> 50% to both of them
if B > A & B < parent layout -> A = parent layout - B
```

I had to do it all in `onWindowFocusChanged` because otherwise in onCreate the height of the Views would return 0. I did it with 2 LinearLayouts as child layouts, but you can take what ever you want.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_lay"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

//Layout A:
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_height="10dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
//Layout B:
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#123456" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout parent_lay;
    LinearLayout lay_1;
    LinearLayout lay_2;
    int parent_height;
    int lay_1_height;
    int lay_2_heigth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        parent_lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_lay);
        lay_1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_1);
        lay_2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_2);
        lay_1_height = lay_1.getHeight();
        lay_2_heigth = lay_2.getHeight();
        parent_height = parent_lay.getHeight();


        if (lay_2.getHeight() > lay_1.getHeight()
                && lay_2.getHeight() > (parent_lay.getHeight() / 2)) {

            lay_1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));

            lay_2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));

        } else if (lay_2.getHeight() < (parent_lay.getHeight() / 2)) {
            lay_1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (parent_height - lay_2_heigth)));

        }

    }

}
```

Example:
If A is **60dp** and B is **40dp**:

[image]

If A is **60dp** and B is **400dp**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all that work, but you didn't quite get the rules right. B Is always parent - A. If A's measured height is less than half of parent use that,  otherwise use half of parent for size of A.

Comment: @dalewking You said "B should get at most 50%." - So not more than 50%, this is exactly what I did. In my Example B *is* always (parent - A), unless it's more then 50%, so the best approach would be if B's original height is greater then 50% that it would get the most space it could get(50%).

Comment: Oops in my reply I reversed A and B. A Is always parent - B. If B's measured height is less than half of parent use that, otherwise use half of parent for size of B.

Focus change is definitely not the place to do this, but there are layout change listeners. Will try with my solution I mentioned below and if that doesn't work will revisit your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must write your own component to achieve this.

For example, if you use LinearLayout here, you can extends a LinearLayout with overdid onMeasure method. You can implement onMeasure like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    final int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    final int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height / 2);
}
```

This code is not elegant enough. If you really want to do it well, copy the original onMeasure method from Android source code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#LinearLayout.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29), and in `measureVertical(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)`, set `mTotalLength = mTotalLength / 2`.

For detailed information of onMeasure, visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int).

Comment: What you have there would make an item take up half the space it would normally take, which is not what I wanted. I want it to take half of its parent space, but only if it is bigger than half of its parent space. If it is smaller it should take only the room it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Now the desired effect can be achieved with the ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/containerFrameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a linear layout with two inner frames, each with `.5` weight. **Inside** those frames, place your views, setting them to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` as appropriate.

Comment: But then the contents of A cannot exceed 50% or can it?

Comment: Doesn't quite get there. Allows a small B to be expanded to 50%.